# understanding rleid behavior, cum sum that resets conditionally

Tags: r, data.table, cumsum

this is the output of `apcpDW = setDT(apcpDW)[, RAIN := cumsum(wm), by = rleid(wday == 2)]`:

```
    timestamp           wm wday         RAIN
 1: 1998-01-01  0.000000000    5  0.000000000
 2: 1998-01-02  0.005644862    6  0.005644862
 3: 1998-01-03  1.580885557    7  1.586530419
 4: 1998-01-04  7.033152468    1  8.619682888
 5: 1998-01-05  8.254771325    2  8.254771325
 6: 1998-01-06  7.309265805    3  7.309265805
 7: 1998-01-07  8.914006707    4 16.223272512
 8: 1998-01-08 13.836810823    5 30.060083334
 9: 1998-01-09  5.516107500    6 35.576190834
10: 1998-01-10  0.201572931    7 35.777763765
```

Why does the running sum not continue between `wday` `2` and `3`? It resets before `2`, then resets again right after `2`. What do I have to change for it to get the sum of `wm` from `2` to the next `1`? (I.e, `wday` `1` will always have the largest value, and the subsequent `2` will be exactly `wm`, then `3` will be `2+3`...etc)

Comment: You can examine `DT[, rleid(wday == 2)]` to see what it looks like.

Comment: If you want the running sum to continue, omit the `by = rleid(wday == 2)` part

Comment: @Frank, it looks like it's a running sort of `id` (?) that increments when it reaches `2`, then increments again right after `2`.... I guess my question is why is there this double increment?

Comment: You can get what you want with `setDT(apcpDW)[, RAIN := cumsum(wm), by = rleid(cumsum(wday == 2))]`. Reading `?rleid` and playing with the results as Frank mentions is worth the effort.

Comment: Note that `rleid(cumsum(wday == 2))` is the same as `cumsum(wday == 2) + 1`